# Macro to compute which element of a bit field is accessed

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

I would want to create a macro to get easy access to a single bit from a structure like the following:

```
typedef union 
{
    struct 
    {
        uint8_t bit0 : 1;
        uint8_t bit1 : 1;
        uint8_t bit2 : 1;
        uint8_t bit3 : 1;
        uint8_t bit4 : 1;
        uint8_t bit5 : 1;
        uint8_t bit6 : 1;
        uint8_t bit7 : 1;
    };
    uint8_t raw;
} Bitfield;
```

I have a bi-dimensional array(x) of this structure. The best that I could make was :

```
#define xstr(r,c,b) str(r,c,b)
#define str(r,c,b) (x[r][c].bit##b)
#define getBit(bitCollum,row)(xstr(row,(bitCollum/8),(bitCollum%8))
```

When I try to use the macro like `uint8_t a = getBit(15,2);` it will expand to

```
 uint8_t a = ( ( img [ 2 ] [ ( 15 / 8 ) ] . bit 15 % 8 ) );
```

and I would want to create a structure that will expand to:

```
 uint8_t a = ( ( img [ 2 ] [ ( 15 / 8 ) ] . bit7 ) );
```

Is this even possible?

`bitCollum` and `row` will always be literal integers; the expression will not be run in a loop or something like that.

**EDIT:**

After seeing that it wasn't possible i looked at the disassembly of a simple increment and I saw different instructions but for my surprise the masking was faster.

```
` x.raw = 0b10101001;
00000040  LDI R24,0xA9      Load immediate 
00000041  STD Y+8,R24       Store indirect with displacement 
   uint8_t y = 0b10101001;
00000042  LDI R24,0xA9      Load immediate 
00000043  STD Y+1,R24       Store indirect with displacement 
   uint16_t xSum=0;
00000044  STD Y+3,R1        Store indirect with displacement 
00000045  STD Y+2,R1        Store indirect with displacement 
   uint16_t ySum=0;
00000046  STD Y+5,R1        Store indirect with displacement 
00000047  STD Y+4,R1        Store indirect with displacement 
   xSum+=x.bit3;
00000048  LDD R24,Y+8       Load indirect with displacement 
00000049  BST R24,3     Bit store from register to T 
0000004A  CLR R24       Clear Register 
0000004B  BLD R24,0     Bit load from T to register 
0000004C  MOV R24,R24       Copy register 
0000004D  LDI R25,0x00      Load immediate 
0000004E  LDD R18,Y+2       Load indirect with displacement 
0000004F  LDD R19,Y+3       Load indirect with displacement 
00000050  ADD R24,R18       Add without carry 
00000051  ADC R25,R19       Add with carry 
00000052  STD Y+3,R25       Store indirect with displacement 
00000053  STD Y+2,R24       Store indirect with displacement 
   ySum+=y&0b00010000;
00000054  LDD R24,Y+1       Load indirect with displacement 
00000055  MOV R24,R24       Copy register 
00000056  LDI R25,0x00      Load immediate 
00000057  ANDI R24,0x10     Logical AND with immediate 
00000058  CLR R25       Clear Register 
00000059  LDD R18,Y+4       Load indirect with displacement 
0000005A  LDD R19,Y+5       Load indirect with displacement 
0000005B  ADD R24,R18       Add without carry 
0000005C  ADC R25,R19       Add with carry 
0000005D  STD Y+5,R25       Store indirect with displacement 
0000005E  STD Y+4,R24       Store indirect with displacement `
```

Comment: why don't you just use & operator. example: `result = variable & ( 0x01000000 )`

Comment: It isn't going to work like that...you'll need to do bit manipulation on the `.raw` member with calculated shifts and masking ops instead.  And worry about the layout of the bits within the byte when accessed via the bit field.  The C standard leaves the order of bits to the discretion of the compiler.  Compilers defer to the ABI on the platform, but there are portability issues galore with bit fields in general.

Comment: i want to write an application that uses as few instructions as possible so i want to use the defines to generate the code for me instead of using for loops for example

Comment: if you are using literal integers, the compiler should easily optimise access to any bit in a 32 or 64 bit field specified by `v&(1<<15)` for example, so trying to get cpp to do it doesnt help. How do you think the compiler will code your `.bit7` access? You should try some examples using `gcc -Os -S` and look at the generated assembler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be that I'm missing some "trick", but, AFAIK, this is not possible.

Basically, you're trying to compute a value and then append it to some token. The problem here is that the preprocessor doesn't do computations (except in #if and such statements). So, for example:

```
#define X2(A,B) A##B
#define X(A,B) X2(A,B)

int x = X(13 + 4, 4);
```

this will expand to:

```
int x = 13 + 44;
```

and *not* to:

```
int x = 174;
```

If you try to put parenthesis, you will just get compiler errors, 'cause this is not valid:

```
int x = (13+4)4;
```

While processing macros, everything is just a "string" (token) to the preprocessor. Actually, it is the compiler that will, in the example above, see that 13 + 44 is constant and compile that as `int x = 57;` (well, an intelligent compiler, I've worked with some C compilers in my day that were not so smart :) ).

Answer (score 3):

Instead of the structures, use simple bytes - uint8_t

```
#define GETBIT(r,c) (img[r][(c) >> 3] & (1 << ((c) & 7)))
#define SETBIT(r,c) img[r][(c) >> 3] |= (1 << ((c) & 7))
#define CLRBIT(r,c) img[r][(c) >> 3] &= ~(1 << ((c) & 7))
```

However, if you want it efficient, you better avoid manipulating things one bit at a time.

Answer (score 0):

```
#define GET_BIT(VAR8,IDX)   ((VAR8>>IDX) & 1)


int main(void){
    unsigned char c=3;
    int i;
    printf("Bits of char %d: ",c);
    for(i=0; i<8;i++){
        printf("%d ",GET_BIT(c,i));
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The question did observe that the macros would only use literals for the bit numbers.

Comment: i demonstrated how to access (read) any bit in the char (BYTE) individually without accessing struct fields .  @PineForestRanch has provide a complete macro for this question.